# How do I control the (templated?) output of field_view_field

Tags: commerce, files

I'm using Billy Mail, Billy PDF and a custom module to generate custom 'booking sheet' documents relating to Commerce orders.  I'm getting different markup generated depending on where the custom code is called from.

The code in question is:

```
// in my_custom.module
$commerce_customer_billing =field_view_field('commerce_order', $order, 'commerce_customer_billing')[0]['#markup'];
...

<!-- in booking_sheet_pdf_page.tpl.php -->
<?php print $commerce_customer_billing; ?>
```

When I call the above through Drupal admin UI, I get complete markup, which is what I want:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-full-name field-type-text field-left-above">
  <div class="field-left">Full name:</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">Testy McTestface</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when the code is called by Billy Mail to generate a PDF email attachment, it outputs just the field value, without any markup:

```
Testy McTestface
```

I'm assuming `field_view_field` is inheriting a template from the theme?  How do I force the field to always render with complete markup, or where do I look for those settings?